# Control query generate in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two databases one for testing and one for production for example database and database_test, I set the connection string to connect to database_test, I don't know, why when I try to access to any row of one table  the query generated add the database production name for example database.TableName and in the other tables only generate a query with TableName without the databaseName. I try adding a schema in a table name in the model but always is adding the database name that it's the production name, instead of generate the queries without database name, why it's this behavior?

**Update**: sorry is EF Core 2.2 from mysql with pomelo, the connection string database is testing, the production database name is production. For example the next code

```
 contexto.Table1
```

is translated in a query select * from production.Table1 instead of only translate in Select * from Table1

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, can you maybe give examples or be more concise?

Comment: Debug your code maybe some code exists that occur that particular problem.

Comment: Which provider are you using? Please provide source code other wise its like a magician who try to guess what is wrong.

Comment: sorry I edit the question

Comment: @abigailarmijo how do you generate the model is it "model.edmx"

Comment: in .net core doesn't exists the model.edmx you only add your clases to a context classs